# Selenium Webdriver with Java: Not able to locate element on the browser popup window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

1. Go to this URL: **https://sports.ladbrokes.com/en-gb/**
2. Click on "JOIN NOW" at the top right of the window
3. It opens a window pop up, where I need to enter 'First name' and other info

Though the 'First name' input box has the input tag with name attribute in the DOM, I am not able to find it with usual way. Please suggest!

When I say usual way, something straight forward like below is not working:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstname']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='First name']"))
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried

Comment: you have to switch that window and then use that code

Comment: Check the code it is working for me. let me know if u have any concern

Comment: Learn it from mukesh otwani tutorial on youtube

Answer (score 0):

It's an iframe which means you have to switch to the iframe first before you can locate elements there.

this is untested but something similar to this

```
driver.switchTo().frame("lightbox-registration-frame") 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstname']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='First name']"))

driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // <- important if need to switch back to original window
```

You may also need to use a wait to allow the iframe to appear/load. I noticed it took a second or 2 to load so if you try to switch immediately you'll end up with an unable to find iframe exception.

Also note that in my example i used "lightbox-registration-frame" to find the iframe which may not necessarily be correct. Generally you want to use the name or id of the iframe which i didn't see so you may need to use an index or some other method to find the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to enter into the iframe and then locate the fields. try below code it works for you:

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://sports.ladbrokes.com/en-gb/");

// click on the Join now button 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='loginSubmit']/div[3]/button[2]")).click();

//find Locator of  frame    
WebElement frampath= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[(@class='lightbox-registration-frame')]"));

//switch to frame for operations
driver.switchTo().frame(frampath);
driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("fdf");
// more operations
//statement1 (operation you want to perform)
//statement2(operation you want to perform)

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Switch to main page       
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: I am a newbie to Selenium. do let me know if there a place where I can read and practice about complex element recognition. Thanks again!

Comment: I am also a  newbie:)